# print the contents of List View in a .net windows Application

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to print the contents of windows form list view, I have done tons of research but most of them take approaches like writing the content to text file then printing the file, or write the content to a web view then using javascript printing the webview, or transforming the content to an image then print....

Is there a direct method or an easier approach to use?

Thanks

Comment: It is pretty easy to get going with PrintDocument.  Although it tends to require a bunch a code to draw the view to paper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want that. You can print the form as it is.

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6he9hz8c.aspx

And instead of using the windows form location, you can put the location of your ListView.

Other idea is to iterate the controls and draw them into a graphic context:

see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printform.aspx to start..

Comment: What if you have scrolling, it only shows the visible part of the form.